# After upgrading to Angular 9, problem with the command "ng lint --fix"

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I am getting this error:

```
[error] Error: Unable to find TSLint. Ensure TSLint is installed.
    at _loadTslint (C:\urm\workspace\project\src\main\ngapp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tslint\index.js:22:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:832:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Any idea what can I do without installing it myself? Everything worked before the upgrade.

Comment: Have you checked whether it is installed? If it's not, why don't you want to install it? Also have you checked the Angular/CLI issues to see if anyone else has this problem?

Comment: it's not installed, I do not have "tslint" in my node_modules, I just thought that maybe I should change something in my config files or something.

Comment: @jonrsharpe TSlint is deprecated